# Angular UI Router - nested states and views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have this index.html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="app" ui-view>
          <h1>This should be visible while the app loads</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

My config code:

```
angular.module('app').config(function ($locationProvider, $stateProvider) {
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: '/res/login/login.tpl.html'
    })
    .state('app', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: '/res/app/app.tpl.html',
        controller: 'AppCtrl',
        abstract: true,
        views:{
            header: {
                templateUrl: '/res/app/header.tpl.html'
            },
            toolbox: {
                templateUrl: '/res/app/toolbox.tpl.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.online', {
        url: 'online',
        templateUrl: '/res/app/online/online.tpl.html'
    })
    .state('app.history', {
        url: 'history',
        templateUrl: '/res/app/history/history.tpl.html'
    });
})    
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$state', function ($state) {

}])
.controller('LoginCtrl', [function () {

}])
.controller('AppCtrl', [function () {

}])
.controller('HeaderCtrl', [function () {

}])
.controller('SidebarCtrl', [function () {

}]);
```

app.tpl.html:

```
<div class="header" ui-view="header"></div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="toolbox" ui-view="toolbox"></div>
    <div class="content" ui-view>
         Place for the states - "app.online" and "app.history"
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the following to happen:

- It should have two main states - Login and App.
- The App state should contain three sub-views: header, toolbox and content. The "content" view is a container for the views of sub-states app.online and app.history.
- After getting into App state, I want the user to navigate between the sub-states app.online and app.history. The App state should be abstract and the default sub-state should be app.online
- URLs:

  `/login` [login state with single view]

  `/` [app state, which should redirect to /online]

  `/online` [app.online state]

  `/history` [app.history state]

Currently, I can load `/login` successfully, but I don't understand why going to `/online` doesn't display app.tpl.html.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main change should be this state defintion:

```
.state('app', {
    url: '/',
    abstract: true,
    views:{
        '': {
            templateUrl: '/res/app/app.tpl.html',
            controller: 'AppCtrl',
        },
        'header@app': {
            templateUrl: '/res/app/header.tpl.html'
        },
        'toolbox@app': {
            templateUrl: '/res/app/toolbox.tpl.html'
        }
    }
})
```

this way we do pass the `app.tpl.html` into the unnamed `ui-view=""` in the index.html (root) next, we target with absolute naming that view, and inject the others:

```
'header@app': {
    templateUrl: '/res/app/header.tpl.html'
},
'toolbox@app': {
    templateUrl: '/res/app/toolbox.tpl.html'
}
```

Check the: **[View Names - Relative vs. Absolute Names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names)** *cite*:

> Behind the scenes, every view gets assigned an absolute name that follows a scheme of **`viewname@statename`**, where viewname is the name used in the view directive and state name is the state's absolute name, e.g. contact.item. You can also choose to write your view names in the absolute syntax.

Comment: Adding a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/jvXM1YjhJTE0h6nZ0OuT?p=preview with an example ;)